# Have a way to view all the flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam, stackexchange.com, flag-history

Can we have a way to see all our flags across all stacks? I have 40+ accounts just to nuke spam and I would like an easy way to see all my flags. It should go under the network profile as a private field. (Just like the one on the site).

---

I want a button or something like that, not support for how do I view all my flags across accounts!

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with *if not all tags match it can't be a dupe*

Comment: It ***is*** a duplicate because the feature you're asking for is not currently available.

Comment: So thats why its a feature request!

Comment: Oh, you're saying something illogical. So the other question is asking for whether there's feature or not, the feature isn't available, then *how* the other question is not a feature request also?

Comment: And also, I've edited the linked question, because *getting* such a feature was obviously the OP's intent.

Comment: @Dro http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259918/have-a-way-to-view-all-the-flags#comment847256_259918

Comment: @nicael Now you use 2k muscle to make this dupe. :( cheats?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259918/have-a-way-to-view-all-the-flags?noredirect=1#comment847257_259918

Comment: @Dro Meta sites allow meta discussion :P

Comment: @Dronehinge `ERROR: SITE NOT FOUND!`